# Forcing Python to pass a variable by value

Tags: python

Let's say I want to create a list of functions programmatically, e.g. I want to create nine functions that, given a number in input, they add it respectively 1, 2, ... 9 and return it.

My take would be to write the following code:

```
>>> functions = []
>>> for i in range(1,10):
...     functions.append(lambda x : x + i)
... 
>>> for f in functions:
...     print(f(0), end=' ')
```

However, the ouput is

```
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

Instead of the expected

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I understand that this has to do with how Python deals with function arguments, i.e. when I create my `lambda`, I bound it to the *reference* of `i`, and not to its *value*.

How can I get around this? Is there a way to force Python to make a copy of `i`, instead of passing is reference?

Comment: [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) may be of use, or ...

Comment: `functions.append(lambda x, i=i: x + i)`

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures